# Youtube comments get deleted after displaying

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Good morning,
I'm having an annoying problem with some thing that's i'm trying to make using the youtube comment api , i'm trying to add automatically a comment when a video on my channel has been uploaded , it works as intended for the first 5 seconds and i get a notification that my comment was added , ,and i can see it after i uploaded my video ,  but after 3 - 5 seconds after , my comment gets deleted on it's own.
i looked for what could the cause of this could be , and i thought " oh maby it's considered as spam " , so i look in my uploaded video comments spam tab , and NOTHING , the comments are no where to be found.
i tried this process for around 10 times and still nothing , can someone help me out please ?
Thank you !

Here's what i do :

I subscribe to the youtube webhook to get a notification when a user uploads a new video

when i receive a notification , i send a push notification to my android app , so i can get an access_token from my android app using the google api.

once i get the token , isend it to my server so i can use it to comment on my new video.

Here is the code i use to insert a comment in the backend ( in node js ) :

```
function insertYoutubeComment(videoId,channel_id,message,access_token,comment){

  

    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads',
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
        },
        body: {
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": videoId,
            "channelId": channel_id,
            "topLevelComment": {
              "snippet": {
                "textOriginal": message
              }
            }
          }
        },
        qs: {
          part: 'snippet',
          access_token: access_token
        },
        json: true
      }, function (error, response, body) {

        console.log('body ==== ', body);

        if (error) {
          console.log('body', error.stack);
          console.log('error in when posting comment ', error.stack);
          resolve(error.stack);
     //     return reject(error);
        }

        console.log("Videos ==== ",comment.video);
let videos = comment.video
videos.push(videoId)
let bod = {}
        console.log("Updating videos ");
        Object.assign(bod, {
       
          video: videos,
        
          });
console.log("Body in update =====",body);
        commentmodel.updateOne(
          { _id: comment._id },
          bod,
          function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Error updating ")
              resolve("comment Error");
          
            } else {
              console.log("Updated user ===",user);
              resolve("comment inserted");
            }
          }
        );
        
        
        //res.json({ message: "Comment inserted", status: 200, data: comment });
       // return resolve(body);
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: @DaImTo it is edited